# Sulla differenza tra gli aggettivi "suo" e "proprio" in una frase particolare

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> Giuseppe Mazzini non propagandò politiche proletarie né nascose nulla circa il suo/proprio essere benestante.

Non sono sicuro se nella frase sopra epigrafata sia corretto scrivere 'suo' o 'proprio' o, ancora, se sono corretti entrambi.

Se l'asserzione, anziché chiudersi con 'essere benestante', si fosse chiusa con 'modo di essere', allora - secondo me - 'suo' e 'proprio' sarebbero stati intercambiabili, ma, non so perché, con la conclusione scelta si ha come l'impressione che 'proprio' non funzioni.

Quindi, qual è la risposta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In generale l'Italiano segue, in modo meno rigido, la regola latina, che vuole l'aggettivo personale *suus* invece di *eius*, se è riferito al soggetto.

Sulla questione *suo* vs *proprio*: 
http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/en/italian-language/language-consulting/questions-answers/impiego

Qui dunque entrambe le forme sono corrette. L'uso di *suo* mi pare più naturale; mi  pare che *proprio* aggiungerebbe una connotazione di qualità caratterizzante/specifica del soggetto: come se si parlasse del modo personale del Mazzini di essere benestante. Per esempio direi "non nascose nulla dei propri ideali/ delle proprie idee politiche".

Comment: Non capisco bene. La citazione dalla Crusca specifica solo casi particolari in cui non si può usare “proprio”, ma non dice che “suo” sia preferibile, o più “naturale”, di “proprio”: perché lo pensi?

Comment: è vero, a pensarci bene è solo una mia impressione: semplicemente non vedo il motivo dell'altra forma un po' più aulica. Ho quindi attenuato la frase e spiegato la mia impressione.